# R effects package Error: non-conformable arguments

Tags: r

I am using `effects` R [package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/effects/index.html) and `effect` function on a cox model. There is a default method for this function so it somehow should work for any model.

When I try to use this function I get this error:

**Any idea how to fix this and what is wrong?**

```
> eff_cf <- effect("TP53:MDM2", model)
Error in mod.matrix %*% mod$coefficients[!is.na(coef(mod))] : 
  non-conformable arguments
```

My model looks like this:

```
> model
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(times, patient.vital_status) ~ TP53 + MDM2 + 
    TP53:MDM2, data = clinForPlot)


                                coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z       p
TP53Other                     -0.163     0.850    0.217 -0.752 4.5e-01
TP53WILD                      -1.086     0.337    0.277 -3.928 8.6e-05
MDM2(1183.7,1674.7]           -0.669     0.512    0.235 -2.851 4.4e-03
MDM2(1674.7,2248.5]           -0.744     0.475    0.305 -2.444 1.5e-02
MDM2(2248.5,50339]            -0.867     0.420    0.375 -2.308 2.1e-02
TP53Other:MDM2(1183.7,1674.7]  0.394     1.483    0.412  0.958 3.4e-01
TP53WILD:MDM2(1183.7,1674.7]   0.133     1.142    0.413  0.323 7.5e-01
TP53Other:MDM2(1674.7,2248.5] -0.192     0.825    0.517 -0.372 7.1e-01
TP53WILD:MDM2(1674.7,2248.5]   0.546     1.726    0.433  1.260 2.1e-01
TP53Other:MDM2(2248.5,50339]  -0.140     0.869    0.650 -0.215 8.3e-01
TP53WILD:MDM2(2248.5,50339]    0.786     2.195    0.484  1.623 1.0e-01

Likelihood ratio test=72.8  on 11 df, p=3.54e-11  n= 1321, number of events= 258
```

And the model and the data.frame used for model can be reproduced using this code

```
library(archivist)
model <- loadFromGitub("68eeefba87be70364eb3801cec58eb3d", 
              user = "MarcinKosinski",
              repo = "Museum",
              value = TRUE)

clinForPlot <- loadFromGitub("cfa5145e6b98964d5f8b760bf749e426", 
                       user = "MarcinKosinski",
                       repo = "Museum",
                       value = TRUE)
```

**Any idea how to fix this and what is wrong?**

Comment: The problem appears to be that the `effects` package doesn't appear to be specially configured for `coxph` objects and `coxph` objects are special in that you cannot estimate an intercept term. The error you are getting is because it is trying to multiple a matrix with an intercept term with the coefficients which do not have an intercept.

Comment: Can I stupidly add intercept somehow :)?